# Loading multiple hbase table qualifiers through PIG

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, apache-pig

I have an hbase table named USERS having a column family name USER_INFO. USER_INFO has two qualifiers EMAIL ,AGE.
When i try to load a single qualifier values thorugh PIG, Its a success. using command:

```
R = LOAD 'USERS' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('USER_INFO:EMAIL', '-loadKey') AS (key: chararray, EMAIL: chararray); 
dump R;
```

but i am not able to load the table using both qualifiers. i.e. EMAIL, AGE.
i tried this :

```
S = LOAD 'USERS' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('USER_INFO:AGE', 'USER_INFO:EMAIL','-loadKey') 
AS (key: chararray, AGE:chararray, EMAIL:chararray);
dump S;
```

it gave error in creating job configuration.
rather i dont know the correct usage of command, that i should give. PLZ HELP!!!!

Comment: `R = LOAD 'USERS' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('USER_INFO:EMAIL USER_INFO:AGE', '-loadKey') AS (key:chararray,EMAIL:chararray,AGE:chararray);
    dump R;`

its working with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
R = LOAD 'USERS' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('USER_INFO:*', '-loadKey') AS (key:chararray,qualifier:map[]); 
dump R
```